# Unable to Figure out IF Statement in Excel with Text Rules

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have to create a binary variable and underneath have a rule that states, if E2 is equal to Twice a Month, Once a Week, More Frequently than Frequent Visitor if not then Infrequent Visitor. I can't figure out how to group these. Screenshot listed.

[image]

Comment: please note what's written in cell E2...

Comment: **Once a Month** is written in E2. Using the above via screenshot, I expected to get Infrequent but only get #Name?.

Comment: The `AND()` operator doesn't make any sense. Your cell can't be equal to 3 different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change AND into OR:

```
=IF(OR(E2="twice a month",E2="once a week", E2="more frequently),"frequent","infrequent")
```